# Which Windows Print API to call from .net program

Tags: c#, file, winapi, sharepoint, printing

I need to print my Files found in my SPFolder directly  to the Printer without recognizing the file type, so which Windows API to call and how to call it ?
Also what's the process to launch the printing job when there are many files to print at the same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the system's file associations to do the printing.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(documentFileName);
psi.Verb = "Print";
Process.Start(psi);
```

This relies on the machine having programs capable of printing all the document types you are interested in.

Comment: what about importing from gdi32.dll and winspool.drv ?

Comment: what's the difference betwwen the code you gave and the function that this dll offers ?

Comment: Those DLLs provide low level drawing and printing services. You want to print Word, Excel, PowerPoint, PDF documents and the like, as I read your question. You need an application to understand those files and in turn be able to print them. That application will ultimately call the low-level routines but you are lost without the application.

Comment: so this code you wrote it will eventually call the low level drawing and printing services, right ?

Comment: That code starts whichever application is associated with the document at hand, and asks the application to print it. The application will load the document and then do whatever it does to print it. Which will no double lead to calls to gdi32. If you want to print effectively any document type imaginable, then you can't do much other than this.

Comment: just one more question does the command psi.Verb = "Print"; display the file before printing it , or printing is done quietly ?

Comment: Depends on the app. I'd expect most to display a window for a short period of time, print, and then disappear.

Comment: that would be a problem to display the file before printing it, because I'll be using this code to print a collection of files found in a folder, so i should not open each one of them and then print then close !

Comment: What alternative do you have? If you want to be able to print any type of file, how else could you hope to do this?

Comment: that's why I was intending to import WIN32.DLL and include extern function to do so .. I guess , in fact I'm still looking for other alternatives that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: Can you give some examples of the type of files you want to print. Excel? Word? PDF? PowerPoint?

Comment: yeah regular doc types nothing fancy

Comment: Er, those are fancy doc types!! It sounds like you are looking for Windows API functions that can print Word and Excel documents. Is that right? Anyway, no such functions exist. You need Word and Excel. Or a 3rd party library like Aspose. No 3rd party library will do the job as well as the original app though.